# Is the Hiring/Offer Process Slower During the Holidays?

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process

I interviewed for a position at a large government contractor on December 12. On December 21, the recruiter called to say they were preparing an offer for me. She asked about my availability start (I said ASAP), confirmed the position would be fully remote, and quoted me a salary (much higher than expected). She then said they’d have to create a new requisition for me (job I interviewed for was not intended to be remote), confirm a few things with hiring manager and other leadership. No timeline was provided for written offer. I haven’t had any communication at all since. However I do see a new requisition was created and my application materials were uploaded to “apply” for it. It closed after two days.

My questions: is the slower timeline because of the holidays? Is creating new requisition to hire someone a slower process, or one that is less guaranteed? Admittedly in the past written offers have come much more rapidly after verbal offers for me, though I’ve never been in a search during this time or year, or had a new req created to be hired. Thanks!

Comment: "Do things take longer when people aren't working?"

Comment: I've been hired a couple times over "the holidays", yes it is a drag. Got another job just before, and had little to do for weeks, but at least I was being paid.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, of course it is.  People are out of office.

Answer (score 4):

You are running into two issues.

1. The time of the year. In the United Sates there are several short work weeks in November, December and January; and the week between Christmas and New Years most offices are a ghost town.  This can slow down the process if step 6 of the hiring process has to be done by the person on vacation; and then the person at step 10 isn't available.
2. The creation of a new job opening.

> She then said they’d have to create a new requisition for me (job I
> interviewed for was not intended to be remote), confirm a few things
> with hiring manager and other leadership. No timeline was provided for
> written offer. I haven’t had any communication at all since. However I
> do see a new requisition was created and my application materials were
> uploaded to “apply” for it. It closed after two days.

They advertised a position, collected resumes, performed interviews (maybe several rounds) and made a decision. Now they have to start the process over again. Because this is remote a different pool of candidates will be qualified. The organization will be required to perform certain steps even if everybody wants you to be the winner.

> Is creating new requisition to hire someone a slower process, or one
> that is less guaranteed?

If they have to justify their decision to several levels of the organization that can take time. The pay might be different. The benefits might be different. They might have to explain why the job that last month could only be done by somebody in the office, can now be done by somebody remote.

In some ways the process was sped up by posting the advertisement during the holidays. They might have only had a handful of candidates apply. If the hiring manager has to document why those were rejected that takes time, so few candidates is good for you.

It is also possible that you could lose. A better candidate could apply for the new job. An internal candidate about to lose their job could be forced upon the hiring manager.

Answer (score 1):

2 things.

1. "large government contractor" These guys are glaciers. They move so slowly it almost looks like they are standing still. For them "Ill get back to you quickly" could mean 6 months from now. This is a warning, from personnel experience.
2. Christmas was 2 weeks ago, New years was 2 days ago. It takes time catch up with everything that was left behind before you went out on holiday.

Have some patience, if nothing happens this week. Politely ping the recruiter.

Comment: Thanks for this perspective! It appears the hiring manager and main recruiter I have been working with have been out until tomorrow. Not surprised things haven’t moved much. They also opened a new requisition to hire me. So many reasons for the lag it appears.